# How to check if rich text editor content is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, rich-text-editor, quill

I have a blog with posts. I also have a rich text editor (**Quill**).

Is it possible to check if the rich text editor has empty content?

> I use Quill (with React, Express JS, MongoDB) and I want to somehow
>   prevent storing the empty value in the database.

The problem is that if I add spaces into the editor the `Quill` will generate empty paragraphs. So no content only empty paragraphs. With the normal input field, I can check for the empty string but what if I have a rich text editor?

**Problem:**

```
<p>                     </p>
```

or even worse

```
<p>                            </p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>       </p>
```

I don't really want to save this into the database. Because I don't want to have empty posts. How can I solve this issue? Can be the solution to somehow check for empty paragraph?.. but what about the `<br>` tag?

Please open this codesandbox and just enter bunch of spaces and click on the button. Open console and you'll see output of the editor.

codesandbox: https://dxqhq.codesandbox.io/

Thank you very much

Comment: Why not use "innerText" in JavaScript? Virtually all browsers today support it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as I understand you only want to save user input only if contains text
so you have to clean the user input from HTML then check the output length

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
body = "<p>test</p>"
hasText = !!body.replace(regex, "").length;
if(hasText) save()
```

Comment: It works! That's what I was trying to achieve. Thank you very much.

Comment: But this skips images..! How could we check this..!?

Comment: What if I wanted to do something similar to this along with `.trim()`? e.g. I have all my content, followed by empty paragraphs: 

`<div>content etc.</div>
<p>     </p>
<p></p>`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if a [QuillJS delta object](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) is empty or has whitespaces only by iterating through the object's `ops` property and checking the `insert` value of each operation. If all `insert` values are whitespace characters or the `ops` array is empty, then the delta object is considered empty or has whitespaces only.

Here is the function that checks if the delta object is empty or has whitespaces only:

```
isDeltaEmptyOrWhitespace(delta) {
    if (delta.ops.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < delta.ops.length; i++) {
        if (delta.ops[i].insert.trim() !== '') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: cool solution, but i would add `if (delta.ops[0].insert instanceof Object) return false` before entering the loop in case of an image as the first element, then `.trim()` will fail cuz its applied on an object.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me so it wouldn't escape images.

```
function isQuillEmpty(value: string) {
   if (value.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '').trim().length === 0 && !value.includes("<img")) {
      return true;
    }
      return false;
    }
```